# How can I trigger a like page action on a remote site?

Tags: triggers, connect, facebook-likebox

I have a web site that accepts visitors registerings.
I want to all a choice in the registering form :
[] Like our page on Facebook.

so if user checked this option in registering, a request will be send to facebook to like this page

I also imagine 
[if he was already logged on in facebook, if not just ignore the request.]
[this request can be done with ajax.get or ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point of time, the ability to "like" a page is strictly allowed only through facebook's own interfaces (site, app etc) and cannot be done by the API or third party apps. I believe that facebook may not allow it in near future too since it may open up serious privacy issues.

You might be better off putting a like plugin in your registration process if that is one of your targets.